# Ignoring some not all in directory git

Tags: git

So I have my structure for my CMS detailed

```
-Root
--Core
---Classes
---Functions.d
---Hooks
---Custom
--App
---Plugins
---Modules
---Themes
---Extensions
-.gitignore
-index.php
-config.php
```

Now From Here I have my `.gitignore` file

```
core/custom/*.class
core/custom/*.hook
core/custom/*.php
config.php
```

What I want to do is basically I have it ignore

```
app/plugins/*
app/modules/*
app/themes/*
app/extensions/*
```

But then I have some integrated modules and plugins that are defaulted into the core. `register_modal` and `login_modal` are two of them. How could I make it so that they are allowed while everything else is ignored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the "not operator" (!) in the .gitignore file to add files back. It is specified in the documentation. [.gitignore](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore)

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for that, I never even noticed that in the docs.